# Is it common for British MPs to have no connection to their electoral district?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, house-of-commons, voting-districts

As an example, Theresa May is serving as an MP from Maidenhead even though she had no connection whatsoever to this constituency since before her election in that constituency. On the other hand Boris Johnson is an MP for Greater London, as could be expected from the former Mayor of London.

Is it common for Members of Parliament to have no connection to their electoral district before the election?

Comment: Although Boris Johnson is now MP for Uxbridge & South Ruislip, which does lie within greater London, he had previously been MP for Henley, which is about 20 miles from the greater London boundary.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachute_candidate#United_Kingdom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Extremley.](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2009/oct/11/labour-selection-parachute-candidates-row) 
The practice is sometimes referred to as "parachuting candidates". All the major parties do it.

Comment: One question about that: in the article you post, it describes this as a scandal. Was the case described in the article particularly blatant, or is it common despite the scandal is causes?

Comment: Extremley common despite the scandal unfortunately. Thats just the newsman pontificating and it hasn't stopped it happening.

Comment: @divibisan It is not scandalous in itself, the scandal is that the democratic process for local nomination of candidates was allegedly subverted.